# Loading page with pathname when a button is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a little bit confused here.
I have a url `locahost/product-location/agro-product` and want when a user clicks on a button on this page it takes the user to `locahost/product/agro-product`. After some research i figured out i could change the pathname this way

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadPage(){
    var theURL = window.location.pathname;
    return  theURL.replace("/product-location/", "/product/");
  }
</script>
```

The above works because if I add this `alert(loadPage());` outside the function: it alerts the new URL path.

Now how do I write the code from here so when a user clicks the button it takes the user to the new URL?

Comment: Normally that type of interaction occurs when you think of things in a client-server setup. A link on a page is actioned on by the server, which serves up a new page. You are thinking purely client. There are round-trips. Http request/responses etc. The server would serve up a new page when the url changes. You may want to also look at how single page applications work too. https://flaviocopes.com/single-page-application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.got it. Just had to do a little rewriting

```
    function loadPage(){


        var theURL = window.location.href;
       return window.location = theURL.replace("/product-location/", "/product/");
        //Set URL

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href`:

```js
function loadPage(){
     var theURL = window.location.pathname;
     var newURL = theURL.replace("/product-location/", "/product/");
     //Set URL
     window.location.href = newURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) because you can choose what window it opens in (not to mention a variety of different options).

```
function loadPage(){
    var newURL = window.location.pathname.replace("/product-location/", "/product/");
    window.open(newURL);

    //LOAD IN NEW WINDOW/TAB INSTEAD:
    //window.open(newURL, "_blank");
}
```

Your button HTML would look like this:

```
<button onclick="loadPage();">Visit new page</button>
```